# Can formattable in R group a table by a variable?

Tags: r, split, group-by, formattable

Is it possible to produce a table using formattable which is grouped by one of the variables in the dataframe? The table could either be divided/split/grouped into separate tables printed consecutively or the groupings are separated within one table.

If not possible with formattable, what other packages and functions could be recommended to create nice looking tables according to the described needs?

In example with this data frame:

```
df <- tibble( 
     x = c(1:100),
     y = c("email","postal")[rep(c(1,2), times=50)],
     c = rep(c("cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4"), times=25) )
```

I would like formattable to produce either 4 tables based for each cat1 to cat4 in variable c for the two columns "x" and "y" or alternatively 1 table with 4 sections for each cat1 to cat4.

Hope anyone can help.

Added after first replys/comments:
To be more specific, how could I get tab1 to tab4 in one go with formattable, preferrably with c as label between each table?

```
library(formattable)
tab1 <- subset(df, c == "cat1")
tab2 <- subset(df, c == "cat2")
tab3 <- subset(df, c == "cat3")
tab4 <- subset(df, c == "cat4")
formattable( tab1  , list(c = FALSE ))
formattable( tab2  , list(c = FALSE ))
formattable( tab3  , list(c = FALSE ))
formattable( tab4  , list(c = FALSE ))
```

Thrid edit: I might have difficulties describing the final need. @ricoderks suggestion takes me almost there.. it does it in one go but the final thing is that I would like all this tables presented in one view/file/output/panel and not four as it is with @ricoderks code. That means I would like only one table output that is sorted and divided in these 4 gorups from variable c, either with formattable or another similar function/tool. I am learning all along from your tips but still not quite where I would liek to be. Thank you again very much for your effort.

[Example of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ9L1.jpg)

Comment: For the sample data you give, there isn't really anything to tabulate per `c` group. So I'm not sure what table(s) you'd like to show. Can you show at least one of the expected output tables for the sample data you give?

Comment: Thx for quick reply. The first answer below is how the tables should be but the problem is to get formattable function to print the four tables in one go to have nice output indicating the different groups. If I subset c I could like this make 4 separate formattable but that is not the intention while I would like them in one go, preferrably separated with c as a label.

Comment: @ErikS, sorry. I don't know how to make one big table, with the "headers" in between.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you can split dataframe based on a group and get a list with separated dataframe:

```r
library(dplyr)
list <- df %>% group_split(c)
names(list) <- unique(df$c)
```

and here the format of `list`:

```r
> list
$cat1
# A tibble: 25 x 3
       x y     c    
   <int> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 email cat1 
 2     5 email cat1 
 3     9 email cat1 
 4    13 email cat1 
 5    17 email cat1 
 6    21 email cat1 
 7    25 email cat1 
 8    29 email cat1 
 9    33 email cat1 
10    37 email cat1 
# … with 15 more rows

$cat2
# A tibble: 25 x 3
       x y      c    
   <int> <chr>  <chr>
 1     2 postal cat2 
 2     6 postal cat2 
 3    10 postal cat2 
 4    14 postal cat2 
 5    18 postal cat2 
 6    22 postal cat2 
 7    26 postal cat2 
 8    30 postal cat2 
 9    34 postal cat2 
10    38 postal cat2 
# … with 15 more rows

$cat3
# A tibble: 25 x 3
       x y     c    
   <int> <chr> <chr>
 1     3 email cat3 
 2     7 email cat3 
 3    11 email cat3 
 4    15 email cat3 
 5    19 email cat3 
 6    23 email cat3 
 7    27 email cat3 
 8    31 email cat3 
 9    35 email cat3 
10    39 email cat3 
# … with 15 more rows

$cat4
# A tibble: 25 x 3
       x y      c    
   <int> <chr>  <chr>
 1     4 postal cat4 
 2     8 postal cat4 
 3    12 postal cat4 
 4    16 postal cat4 
 5    20 postal cat4 
 6    24 postal cat4 
 7    28 postal cat4 
 8    32 postal cat4 
 9    36 postal cat4 
10    40 postal cat4 
# … with 15 more rows

attr(,"ptype")
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# … with 3 variables: x <int>, y <chr>, c <chr>
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thanx for your input - yeah this is partially how I want to go. But I would like this output clean in the nice formattable format (or equivalent) in one go, not as four seperate table as the edited code in my question would give.

Comment: With `lapply(list, formattable)` you can create all nice tables.

Comment: @ricoderks, you should write an answer with this as it is what the OP is looking for

Comment: I did add a little more to the first question - sorry if not beeing able to express the need as good as i should.

Comment: No problem, it is not always easy to put appropriate words on what we want. Does the solution of @ricoderks is working for you ?

Comment: hi @dc37 - please see image I attached at the end of my question for a sample made in photoshop of how it should look like.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about this package. In order people can see our discussion in comments, I let my answer until someone post a better one and then I will delete it.